# How to pass a variable in @selector (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

If I have

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(somefunction:)];

-(void)somefunction :(id) sender{}
```

What is the right syntax to pass a variable to somefunction? I tried (but it is not working)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(somefunction: somensstring:)];

-(void)somefunction: (NSString *) somestuff :(id) sender{}
```

Comment: What stuff do you need to pass?

Comment: a simple nsstring. The function get the tap on an image beside a cell of UITableView. Using UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender; and gesture.view.tag i'm able to get the cell tapped id but not is text. So i was thinking to directly pass the nsstring containing cell text.

Comment: you can't do that. it's meaningless. you don't call this method. the system calls it when the screen is tapped. the system doesn't have an idea what string you're going to pass

Comment: Not possible directly. Usually, you'd give your sender the properties you want to have available to your method, since your method has access to the sender object.

Comment: If you get the cell tapped, why can't you cast it and refer to it's properties? Otherwise get the index of the cell and refer to your model.

Comment: dirkgroten and Legoless, your comments are very interesting but you think i'm better in coding than i really am ^^ How i can give properties to sender or cast the cell tapped and refer to his properties?

Comment: @ElisabettaFalivene why even have gesture recogniser if you're dealing with UITableViewCell. why don't you use didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Because the cell is made of an image and a text. When the user taps the text it is led to a 'detail' view and when taps the image something else happens. The tap gesture is inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath. In particular, if you need to know, there is a star beside the text representing an ice cream name. If you tap the name it shows informations on it in an another view. If you tap the star, it changes to lit star and you happily chose that ice cream like your favorite.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha There is a lot of legitimate reasons why to use a tap recognizer instead of `didSelectRow`. For example, to solve collisions between recognizers inside the cell and cell selection. There are problems in this question but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should define your `somefunction` method in this way,

`-(void)somefunction:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {};`

#### Easy way

```
-(void)somefunction:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    UIView *view = (UIView *)sender.view; 
    //1.here you can take any view, UILabel, UIImageView or anything on which you've 
    //added tap gesture

    //2.now, distinguish view by tag
    if(view.tag == someTag1) {
        //create a NSString to use when tap
    }
    else if(view.tag == someTag2) {
        //do something else
    }
};
```

#### Let make it little complex

- Define the same method (as above)
  but the view which you're taking from recognizer, make it subclass.
- For e.g. if you've set tap gesture on `UILabel` then make a sub class of `UILabel` and then add gesture on it.
- Also add the properties which you need with that sub class.
- At the time of adding gesture to it, also set variables (or anything) to it.
- So it'll be still available to you when a user tapped.

here's the example of `UILabel` sub class,

```
@interface MyCustomLabel : UILabel 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someString;
@end;
```

Now you can use this custom label like this,

```
#import "MyCustomLabel.h"

MyCustomLable *lbl = [[MyCustomLable alloc] init];
lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,50);
//add gesture on label
lbl.someString = @"Some text";
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

Now the above method will be change little,

```
-(void)somefunction:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    MyCustomLabel *lbl = (MyCustomLabel *)sender.view; 
    NSLog(@"My String %@",lbl.someString);
};
```

Comment: The problem was about tapping an imageView beside a cell in a UiTableView and getting the name on the label of the cell hitten. I tried your method, creating a new class 'BesideImage' inheriting from UiImageView and having as property an UiTableViewCell. Then i added i create a variable of type BesideImage called 'star', did star=cell.imageView inside this variable and tried to do star.cell=cell. Doing this caused a 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setCell:]: unrecognized selector' Maybe do you have an hint of the reason?

Comment: Yes, that's because your imageview don't have setcell setter.

Comment: so if i add a UiTableViewCell as a property it doesn't take with it all his setter and getter?

Answer (score 2):

//add tap gesture

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleTap:)];
```

//Get TouchLocation in TableView

```
-(void)HandleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:theTableView];

    NSIndexPath *theIndexPath = [theTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
}
```

you Can get whatever info you want as per indexPath of tableView From Array;

Comment: Morally this was the solution to my problem. Thank you very much! Sorry not to chose your answer, but, due to the general way i proposed the question, the right one is Hermang's. Hope this doesn't annoy you ^^' Thank you again!